# Spring Retryable - Async context

Tags: java, interrupted-exception, spring-retry

Have an issue with @Retryable in the Async context, I have a service call which is returning a SocketTimeOut exception. This I would have expected to retry 3 times, I do have @EnableRetry, however I am seeing something I little strange in the logs, a sleep interruptedException. Here is part of the stack trace.

> Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
>   at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>   at someservice.somemethod(someservice.java) ~[classes/:na]
>   2018-01-18 18:59:39.818  INFO 14 --- [lTaskExecutor-1] someExceptionHandler : Thread interrupted while sleeping; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
>   at org.springframework.retry.backoff.ThreadWaitSleeper.sleep(ThreadWaitSleeper.java:30) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>   at org.springframework.retry.backoff.StatelessBackOffPolicy.backOff(StatelessBackOffPolicy.java:36) ~[spring-retry-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_141]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]
>   at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.8.RELEASE]

Not sure if this is a red herring here, but this happens after the read timeout occurs, I would have expected it to retry but rather I am seeing this in the logs. I know Spring retry has a default wait of 1 second, I am wondering if its being interrupted thus having an impact on its ability to retry.

T.I.A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted at

Simply means that something else in your app is interrupting the thread while it is waiting in the backOff, thus killing the retry scenario.

This is by design...

```
if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    this.logger
            .debug("Abort retry because interrupted: count="
                    + context.getRetryCount());
}
```

...when you interrupt a thread, you are explicitly telling it to stop what it's doing (if it's doing something interruptible, such as sleeping).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gary - so what happens if we have not specified a backoff policy - so really our method is annotated with @Retryable with no options - is the back off zero or does it default to 1 second? I read that it may be zero? 

So I was able to recreate by adding the following line - 
Thread.currentThread.interrupt(), I seen it stop the retry, however I got the same error BUT that thread I interrupted should have been running not sleeping yet I got the sleep interrupted issue.

Its a basic SSL sockets connection that timed out, I'll try obfuscate some code, and add it if needed

Comment: You can use a `NoBackOffPolicy` to avoid the sleep, but that can't be wired in using the `@Retryable` annotation; you would have to wire up an interceptor as a `@Bean` and use the `interceptor` property on the annotation.

Comment: So just to confirm by default (annotation with no options) the thread will sleep? By adding the interceptor, and providing the NoBackOffPolicy it wont?

Comment: Marked as correct, this should work for me, given the timeout for SSL socket call is 15 seconds anyway - there really shouldn't be a need to sleep. Will see how it goes, thanks for the info!

Comment: Real quick follow up - can we not just do this - 

{@Retryable(backoff = @Backoff(0))}

Comment: Unfortunately, no; with the sleep based backOff policies, any value <= 0 is coerced to 1ms and, in any case, `Thread.sleep()` is called unconditionally and it will interrupt even if the sleep is 0.